# Multiply last 4 record in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I want multiplication on value field in last 4 record in mongodb

I have the following data

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d38f4509717526ea8469c"),
    "code" : "302",
    "value" : 123,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-02T15:44:52.012Z"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-09-02T15:44:52.012Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d38f4509717526ea8469e"),
    "code" : "340",
    "value" : 8,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-02T15:44:52.013Z"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-09-02T15:44:52.013Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d38f4509717526ea8469d"),
    "code" : "327",
    "value" : 23,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-02T15:44:52.013Z"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-09-02T15:44:52.013Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d491d509717526ea8469f"),
    "code" : "301",
    "value" : 3.48,
    "timestamp" : ISODate("2019-09-02T16:53:49.560Z"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2019-09-02T16:53:49.560Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

and I want to multiply the last 4 records of each code and multiply them, Something like this

last records of each code and multiply all code value and get 1 value.

Comment: can you elaborate? multiply with what? get 1 value per code?

Comment: I want multiplication of code 301 * code 302. But code 301 and 302 is the last entry of the database

Comment: So if i understand correct you want the Last document of each code, then multiply the value of the bottom 4 of those?

Comment: yes correct I want multiplication of last 4 code entries

Answer (score 0):

The more "proper" way to do this would look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {  // can remove this step if same code docs are sorted in database
            $sort: {
                createdDate: -1
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$code",
                root: {$last: "$ROOT"}
            }
        },
        {  
            $sort: {
                "root.createdDate": -1
            }
        },
        {
            $limit: 4
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                values: {$push: "$root.value"}
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                total:
                    {
                        $reduce: {
                            input: "$values",
                            initialValue: 1,
                            in: {$multiply: ["$$value", "$$this"]}
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
])
```

However on large scale the "proper" way is not really that efficient as you have to scan the entire collection every time.

If indeed that is your case i recommend either using heuristics to fetch a certain amount of documents by sorting and limiting or just batch fetching until the condition is met and then doing the calculation in code. (this is dependant on how your data distribution is)